# JAXB how to handle inheritance

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I followed the tutorial by [Blaise](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html), where he explains how to output xml from objects where one inherit from the other.

I can however not get this to work the other way around. I have two objects (Actually its a far more complicated model). In essence, one inherit from the other, but when I provide it with the xml, it tries to create an instance of the base class. It can't since its an abstract class.

Does anyone have an example of how I can do this?

Comment: What did not work? Post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Not sure how this can be off-topic. See the answer provided by Blaise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `JAXBContext` is aware of the subclass.  This can be done by passing in the subclass when creating the `JAXBContext` or by using the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the super class to point to all the mapped subclasses.